# Is it possible to install Xdebug on Ubuntu 16 for PHP 7.2 and Apache?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, xdebug

I have Ubuntu 16 with Apache 2 and running PHP 7.2. I have Xdebug 2.4 installed but apt is saying that is the latest version. Xdebug 2.4 does not support PHP 7.2 which I need.

Is there some way to make allow installation of Xdebug 2.7 or greater? Probably 2.7 is safest since it is lowest version that supports PHP 7.2.  Thanks for any instructions on how this can be done.

I tried to do `apt-get update xdebug`, but it is already at 2.4 and won't suggest higher.

Comment: Ubuntu 16 and PHP 7.2 were both end-of-lifed two years ago. They are dangerously insecure to continue running.

Comment: Also, apt is lying. The latest version to support PHP 7.2 is Xdebug 3.1: https://xdebug.org/docs/compat